# How to load an NSView on an NSWindow dynamically?

Tags: cocoa

I have two nib files. One has an NSWindow and the other one has NSView. I want the NSView to load on the NSWindow at the runtime. I understand that i will have to use the NSWindowController and the NSViewController classes. But i just cant figure out how.
I am new to cocoa..Please guide me as to how to achieve this.
If possible, can u direct me to some sample app or guide for this?
Thanks in advance..

UPDATE::
  See comments in line

```
@interface ViewAvailableItemsWindowController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow * viewAvailableItemsWindow; //Window in question
    IBOutlet NSView * viewAvailableItemsView; //View in question

    ItemSearchViewController * instanceItemSearchView; //ViewController object 
}

@end


@implementation ViewAvailableItemsWindowController

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [viewAvailableItemsWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    instanceItemSearchView = [[ItemSearchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ItemSearchView" bundle:nil] ; //Initiating the viewController with the nib for the view.
    [viewAvailableItemsView addSubview:[instanceItemSearchView view]];  //Adding the subview to the window..

}

-(void)dealloc{
    [instanceItemSearchView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

//EDIT regarding to your question you first set the `contentView` of your `NSWindow` to be the `itemsView`. You can do this once eg. in `viewDidLoad` or `init` / `awakeFromNib`:

```
viewAvailableItemsWindow.contentView = viewAvailableItemsView;
```

then to make the view dynamic add new items to the `window.contentView`:

```
[viewAvailableItemsWindow.contentView addSubview:[instanceItemSearchView view]];
```

to remove the old and add new ones call `removeFromSuperview` on the old and then add the new like above

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the window already has a view that you want to insert the loaded view into, you need to tell the existing view in the window to add the new view as a subview.

The [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/) has more information.

Comment: I think he was looking for a mini tutorial and some help, not a RTFM comment.

Comment: Its not a he, its a she :) (very late but still wanted to correct u ;))

Comment: The link is now dead :\